# Angular 6 - importing a library which requires files

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

For reference, I'm trying to get https://github.com/broofa/node-mime to work in my NG 6 project. My understanding is that there's currently no way to modify the webpack configuration in an NG 6 project built on the Angular CLI.

Basically, I would like to import into my project a package which contains `require` calls to some json files that are part of the package.

I get the following error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/index.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './types/other' in 'C:\Dev\LabOrdersAndResultsUI\node_modules\mime'

This tells me that *./types/other.json* is not being packaged when webpack runs.

What is the best way to solve this without getting the package maintainer to provide other versions?